# Biblatex multiple indexes with trailing commas

Tags: biber, indexing

The MWE is modelled on `21-indexing-multiple.tex` but has two issues.  Firstly, the author and title indexes have trailing commas.  Secondly, I'd prefer to have only the first author et al of a work go into the author index (e.g. Chidiac, P. et al, 2, 3 only and neither Beaucourt nor Quantin)

MWE

```
%
%   latex        file
%   bibtex/biber file
%   latex        file
%   makeindex -o file.ind file.idx (= makeindex file)
%   makeindex -o file.nnd file.ndx
%   makeindex -o file.tnd file.tdx
%   latex        file
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,indexing,backend=biber,datamodel=\jobname]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article{doe1981,
    Author = {Doe, John Jack},
    indexname = {Doe, John Jack},
    Journal = {Journal of Nothing},
    Pages = {164--178},
    Title = {More Great Stuff},
    Volume = {4},
    Year = {1981}}

    @book{CHID2004,
       Author = {Chidiac, P. and Quantin, J.-C. and Beaucourt, D.},
       indexname = {Chidiac, P.},
       title = {{Un standard pour l'an 2000 - Tome 2}},
       language = {francais},
       publisher = {Fédération Française de Bridge},
       month=jui,
       date = {2004}
}
@book{RODW2012,
       Author = {Rodwell, E.},
       indexname = {Rodwell, E.},
       title = {{Eric Rodwell: The Bridge World Interview}},
       publisher =  {The Bridge World},
       page={26},
       date = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{index}
\newindex{default}{idx}{ind}{Index}
\newindex{names}{ndx}{nnd}{Index des auteurs}
\newindex{titles}{tdx}{tnd}{Ouvrages cités}

\RequirePackage[unicode=true, psdextra, colorlinks=true, linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex_legacy}
  {\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
     \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[names]}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}
  {\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
     \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[names]}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiven}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[titles]}{#1}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
  \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{author}%
     \indexnames{editor}%
     \indexnames{translator}%
     \indexnames{commentator}%
     \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\DeclareNameFormat{mygiveninit-family}{%
\usebibmacro{name:given-family}%
  {\namepartfamily}%
  {\namepartgiveni}%
  {\namepartprefix}%
  {\namepartsuffix}%
\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}%

\newbibmacro*{cite:fullpartcite}{%
  \printnames[mygiveninit-family]{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{title}%
  \setunit{.}%
}%

\DeclareCiteCommand{\Bridgecite}[\mkbibfootnote]%
{\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
 \usebibmacro{cite:fullpartcite}}%
 {\multicitedelim}%
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}%       


\begin{document}

Cette convention était popularisée par l'équipe Meckwell.  \Bridgecite{RODW2012}  

\newpage

On suit le livre de \Bridgecite{CHID2004} 

\newpage

% We print the printbibliography...
\printbibliography
% ...and the indexes
\raggedright
\printindex         % the general index
\printindex[names]  % the name index
\printindex[titles] % the title index
\end{document}
```

Comment: I presume this punctuation style is intentional, but I'd prefer e.g. a colon rather than a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-makeindex/ documents that

```
"Delimiter to be inserted between a level 0 key and its first page number is delim_0 <string> ", "(default: comma followed by a blank)"
```

So changing this to delim_0  ": " in a .ist file should work.

Here's myfile.ist for example:

```
preamble

    "\\documentstyle[11pt]{book}
    \\begin{document}
    \\begin{theindex}
    {\\small\n"
    postamble
    delim_0 ": "
    "\n\n}
    \\end{theindex}
    \\end{document}\n"
```

Running that as `makeindex -s myfile.ist authors` for the author index gives the required result

```
Index des auteurs
Lévy, A.: 5
Fédération Française de Bridge: 3
Rodwell, E.: 11
```

Re the second question of how to index authors and titles - one would like to have a single command that did both the citations and the author/title indexing.  There must be a way to do that within BibLaTeX but I went for a simpler solution along the lines of

```
\newcommand{\Bridgeciteindex}[1]{\Bridgecite{#1}\sindex[aut]{\authorGet{#1}}\sindex[tit]{\titleGet{#1}}}
```

The first element is a customized footnote citation and the second two use `\usepackage[makeindex]{splitidx}` for authors and titles respectively.  They take  key-val pairs from a pre-generated lookup table which can be generated from the .bib file.  These look like e.g

```
\authorPut{RODW2012}{{Rodwell, E.}} 
\titlePut{RODW2012}{{Eric Rodwell: The Bridge World Interview}}
```

and the whole table becomes an input file.

The Put/Get code is copied from [Capacity exceeded while implementing lookup table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249524/capacity-exceeded-while-implementing-lookup-table)

Output looks like

```
Ouvrages cités                    
Eric Rodwell: The Bridge World Interview, 1        
Un standard pour l’an 2000 - Tome 2, 5
```

Still had the probably correct, but misleading, trailing comma.  That's now corrected :-)