# Need help with improving this hashtable lookup code

Tags: macros, errors, packages

This is based on this post originally:
[Capacity exceeded while implementing lookup table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249524/capacity-exceeded-while-implementing-lookup-table/249529#249529)

A very good solution was posted there.  For my purposes, I wanted to enhance that original solution so that a key collision would report an error instead of simply overwriting it.
I have already implemented that and it works.

However, I encountered a second issue which is that it is possible to do a `\lookupPut` with an invalid second parameter value (the value to be stored).  The `\lookupPut` does not detect this problem.  The error is generated downstream when a `\lookupGet` is done, and an error is generated which does not seem indicative of the issue.

I don't know how to code to detect that invalid second parameter value condition.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my modified `lookup.sty`:

```
% !TeX root = lookup.sty


%%% lookup.sty %%%
%\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{lookup}[2015/06/10 Lookup for custom details]


%
%
% 
%   \lookupGet{key}
%        returns the value for that key
%
\newcommand{\lookupGet}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{lookup@#1}{%  
    \PackageError{lookup}{No #1 key in lookup}{%
      Key #1 was not found in lookup. %
      You can insert it with \string\lookupPut{key}{value}.%
    }%
  }{%
    \@nameuse{lookup@#1}%
  }%
}


%%
%%  \lookupPut{key}{value for that key}
%%
%\newcommand{\lookupPut}[2]{%
%  \@namedef{lookup@#1}{#2}%
%}

%
%  \lookupPut{key}{value for that key}
%
\newcommand{\lookupPut}[2]{%
    \@ifundefined{lookup@#1}{%  
            \@namedef{lookup@#1}{#2}%
        }%
    {%
        \PackageError{lookup}{Key #1 already defined when attempted lookupPut}{%
            Key #1 was already defined when a lookupPut attempted. %
        }%  
    }%
}%

\endinput
```

And here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lookup}

\newcommand{\keyone}{keymono}
\newcommand{\keytwo}{keyduo} 
\newcommand{\keythree}{keytreble}  

\newcommand{\dogone}{labrador}
\newcommand{\dogtwo}{collie}

\lookupPut{\keyone}{\dogone}

%\lookupPut{\keyone}{\dogtwo}  % will now throw an error (good!). Should use \keytwo



\newcommand{\catone}{siamese}

\lookupPut{\keythree}{\cattwo}  % should be \catone.  No error generated!



\begin{document}

Hello world.  I like \lookupGet{\keyone}.  %  This line is OK

Hello world.  I like \lookupGet{\keythree}.

% However, the lookupGet above generates the error:  
%   Undefined control sequence. Hello world. I like \lookupGet{\keythree}
% The desired behavior is for the lookupPut to detect the problem with
% \cattwo so that it can throw an error.




\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @mkstreet and welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add the warning/error message given?

Comment: I think instead of `\@namedef{lookup@#1}` you want `\expandafter\protected@edef\csname lookup@#1\endcsname`...

Comment: @TobiBS It is there already in the comments in the code I posted.  Again:  "Undefined control sequence. Hello world. I like \lookupGet{\keythree}"

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Hi, thanks.  I tried that.  That stops the error from happening on the '''\lookupGet''', but then the print line just shows blanks (for the non-existent value).  Ideally, I want to detect the null/blank value on the '''\lookupPut'''.  Can that be done>

Comment: @mkstreet It sure can, it just depends what do you want to happen. In your version `\lookupPut{\keythree}{\cattwo}` doesn't generate an error because it just defines `\lookup@keytreble` to contain `\cattwo`, which doesn't have to be defined. Then, when you try to use it in `\lookupGet{\keythree}` TeX complains about the `\cattwo` from before not being defined (now you're actually using it).  Adding `\protected@edef` as I suggested forces the expansion of `\cattwo` at the time `\lookup@keytreble` is defined.  What exactly do you want to happen for empty or undefined arguments?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I would like the \lookupPut to report an error on \cattwo because \cattwo is not defined.  For the line \lookupPut{\keythree}{\cattwo}.  In the real document, a typo in the name \cattwo could happen and I would like that to report an error and stop compilation.

Comment: @mkstreet Then my suggestion from the first comment should do.  It will raise an `Undefined control sequence` error in the `\lookupPut` line.  However this error means the undefined `\cattwo` will be ignored and `\lookup@keytreble` will be defined empty.  Having the compilation stop on such an error is a lot harder (and it seems a bit too much)...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  Maybe I did not implement your suggestion correctly.  I only changed this part:

`\newcommand{\lookupGet}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{lookup@#1}{%  
    \PackageError{lookup}{No #1 key in lookup}{%
      Key #1 was not found in lookup. %
      You can insert it with \string\lookupPut{key}{value}.%
    }%
  }{%
    \expandafter\protected@edef\csname lookup@#1\endcsname%
  }%
}`

What I meant about compilation stopping was... just to trap this condition and call PackageError like this module already does for other situations.

Comment: @mkstreet No, you have to replace `\@namedef{lookup@#1}` by `\expandafter\protected@edef\csname lookup@#1\endcsname`. `\@namedef{<smth>}` is the same as `\expandafter\def\csname <smth>\endcsname`, so you are essentially replacing `\def` by `\edef`, which forces the expansion of `\cattwo` at the time of the definition.

Comment: How to handle this: `\def\cattwo{persian}...\lookupPut{\keythree}{\cattwo}...\let\cattwo=\undefined... \lookupGet{\keythree}` ?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Oh I see the line you mean.   How does the second parameter fit into your revised line of code?  Now that line says:
`\@namedef{lookup@#1}{#2}%`
But I don't see the 2nd parameter in your code?

Comment: @mkstreet As I said, replace `\@namedef{lookup@#1}` by `\expandafter\protected@edef\csname lookup@#1\endcsname`, so the entire line will be `\expandafter\protected@edef\csname lookup@#1\endcsname{#2}`. I can post an answer maybe tomorrow...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I got it now, thanks!  Do you want to post as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: This solution works in the MWE, but actually in the real document it doesn't work.

Comment: In the real document, the stored values might contain LaTex code and when this change to  lookupPut now expands them, it leads to new errors on those.  This is probably getting too complicated to resolve this....

Comment: You wish `\lookupPut` to examine whether expanding its second argument (the definition text for the key) leads to error-messages. The second argument/definition text may consist of (almost) arbitrary sequences of tokens. Thus you wish a mechanism which checks whether an algorithm formed by an arbitrary sequence of tokens will terminate properly. Beneath other problems you face the so-called [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem): How do you wish to handle scenarios of never ending recursion as in: `\newcommand\weird{\weird}..\lookupPut{\KeyWeird}{\weird}`?

Comment: @UlrichDiez No, not really.  I just wanted the \lookupPut to test if the first argument was already in the hashtable or not.  If it was not in the hashtable, then define by pairing it with the second arugment.  If the first argument was already in the hashtable, then report that condition as a Package Error.  Now, if the first argument is already in the hastable, the existing entry is overwritten and replaced.

Comment: @mkstreet In your question you write about "an invalid _second_ parameter value". Now its about an invalid _first_ parameter; invalid because already in the hashtable. Sorry, but this is not the kind of stringency that I can handle. All I can tell: You can use the LaTeX-kernel--macro `\@ifdefinable`, e.g., something like `\expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname CS\endcsname{<Tokens in case \CS is definable>}`, which in case of `\CS` being already defined throws an error and otherwise delivers `<Tokens in case \CS is definable>`. ...

Comment: @mkstreet ...  If you wish to have a Package-Error, look up the definition of `\@ifdefinable` via `\show` and define your own macro where the definition is moodified accordingly.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I think I had already decided this was as good as it can get and not practical to be solvable further.  This is done.